# Laravel Elixir Webpack jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, gulp, webpack

It comes with Laravel 5.3 and I am new to Webpack.

Can anyone help me as I keep getting this error:

```
$(...).liteuploader is not a function ..
```

[image]

bootstrap.js:

```
window.$ = window.jQuery = require('jquery');
require('bootstrap-sass');
require('lite-uploader/src/liteuploader.js);
```

app.js

```
require('./bootstrap');

$(function(){
  $('.file-uploader').liteUploader();
  $(".file-uploader").change(function () {
    $(this).data("liteUploader").startUpload();
  });
});
```

gulpfile.js

```
const elixir = require('laravel-elixir');
elixir((mix) => {
    mix.sass('app.scss')
       .webpack('app.js');
});
```

Comment: Were you able to get to the bottom of it ?

Comment: @AngelinCalu yup :)